# Partial Differential when a variable is a function of itself

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am given the following:
$$ z = f(\frac{ny-mz}{nx -lz}) $$
And I have to show that
$$ (nx-lz) \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + (ny-mz) \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0$$
The book I am referring to proceeds in the following way:
$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = f'(\frac{ny-mz}{nx -lz})\cdot(ny-mz)\cdot\frac{-n}{(nx-lz)^2}$$

But shouldn't it be
$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = f'(\frac{ny-mz}{nx -lz})\cdot[(ny-mz)\cdot\frac{-(n -l \frac{\partial z}{\partial x})}{(nx-lz)^2} + \frac{(-m)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}}{(nx-lz)}]$$

According to my understanding if we are computing the differential change in $z$ wrt $x$, then it cannot be treated as a constant anywhere it appears in the equation. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, and the required identity $(nx-lz) z_x+ (ny-mz) z_y= 0$ holds.

For the sake of simplicity, let $u=ny-mz$ and $v=nx -lz$. Then, according to your computation,
$$z_x=f'\big(\frac{u}{v}\big)\cdot \frac{u_xv-uv_x}{v^2}.$$
Similarly,
$$z_y=f'\big(\frac{u}{v}\big)\cdot \frac{u_yv-uv_y}{v^2}.$$
It follows that
$$z_x(u_yv-uv_y)-z_y(u_xv-uv_x)=0$$
which implies
$$z_x((n-mz_y)v-u(-lz_y))-z_y((-mz_x)v-u(n-lz_x))=0$$
that is
$$n vz_x  -mvz_xz_y+ulz_xz_y+mvz_xz_y+nuz_y-ulz_xz_y=0$$
or
$$n(vz_x+uz_y)=0$$
and we are done. Notice that if $n=0$ then $z = f(\frac{-mz}{ -lz})=f(\frac{m}{l})$ is constant and $z_x=z_y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The rule for differentiation of implicitely defined functions is

$$ F[x,y,z]=0  \implies  \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}|_{y=\text{const}} = - \frac{\partial_x F}{\partial_z F}$$

where partial derivatives of $F(x,y,z)$ are denoting the directional derivatives without the constraint $F=0$

Using Mathematica for the algebra
$$ (n x-l z) \left(-\frac{\frac{\partial \text{$\#$1}}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial \text{$\#$1}}{\partial z}}\&\right)\left(z-f\left(\frac{n y-m z}{n x-l z}\right)\right)+(n y-m z) \left(-\frac{\frac{\partial \text{$\#$1}}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial \text{$\#$1}}{\partial z}}\&\right)\left(z-f\left(\frac{n y-m z}{n x-l z}\right)\right)  ==0 $$

```
True
```